# Using jQuery to edit innerHTML()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, innerhtml

I am a total beginner to jQuery. I'm trying to make the page replace the spans inner html with the value that the user types before pressing the button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      // Get value on button click
      $('button').click(function() {
          var str = $('#formValue').val();
        } else {
          str = "empty"
        }
        $('#adVar').html(str);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="formValue" placeholder="type 
        something here">
<button id="submitButton">enter</button>
<p>So now whatever you put in that field should appear here: "<span id="adVar">this 
         is the value we're replacing</span>".
</p>
```

```js
function advancedFunction() {
  
  if ( document.getElementById("formValue").value ) {
    // grab the value from the form, but we'll need to set a listener (below) since it changes when you click the button
    var theVar = document.getElementById("formValue").value;
  } else {
    theVar = "empty";
  }
  // now that we have a value for the form field, let's output it to the field
  document.getElementById("advancedVar").innerHTML = theVar;


document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", advancedFunction);

});
```

Comment: Your `$(document).ready(` isn't closed properly. It's missing a `)`

Comment: Is this the full code? Because it missing many things. How come this snippet has `else` statement without `if` before?

Comment: There is a javascript function that I am trying to rewrite using jquery. I'm going to add that real quick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this method :

```js
$("#submitButton").click(function(){
   var value=$("#formValue").val()
   var advar=$('#adVar')
   if(value.length>1){
      advar.html(value);
   }else{
      advar.html("empty");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="formValue" placeholder="type something here">
<button id="submitButton">enter</button>
<p>So now whatever you put in that field should appear here: "       
   <span id="adVar">this is the value we're replacing</span>".
</p>
```